# Bash regex to match dots and characters

Tags: regex, bash, shell

I'm trying to use the **=~** operator to execute a regular expression pattern against a curl response string.

The pattern im currently using is:

```
name\":\"(\.[a-zA-Z]+)\"
```

Currently however this pattern only extracts values that that contain only the characters a-z and A-Z. I need this pattern to also pick up values that contain a '.' character and a '@' character. How would I do this?

Also, is there any way this pattern can be improved performance wise? It takes quite a long time to execute against the string.

Cheers.

Comment: More useful would be to see how you are using that pattern in your code.

Answer (score 6):

I recently ran into this problem in my script that sets my bash prompt according to my git status, and found that it was because of the placement of other things (namely, a hyphen) I wanted to match inside the expression.

For example, I wanted to match a certain part of a `git status` output, e.g. the part where it says `"Your branch is ahead of 'origin/mybranch' by 1 commit."`

This was my original pattern:

```
"Your branch is (ahead of|behind) '([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)' by ([0-9]+) commit".
```

One day I created a branch that had a `.` in it and found that my bash prompt wasn't showing me the right thing, and modified the expression to the following:

```
"Your branch is (ahead of|behind) '([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9_-.]+)' by ([0-9]+) commit".
```

I expected it to work just fine, but instead there was no match at all.

After reading a lot of posts, I realized it was because of the placement of the hyphen (`-`); I had to put it right after the first square bracket, otherwise it would be interpreted as a range (in this case, it was trying to interpret the range of `_-.`, which is invalid or just somehow makes the whole expression fall over.

It started working when I changed the expression to the following:

```
"Your branch is (ahead of|behind) '([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/([-a-zA-Z0-9_.]+)' by ([0-9]+) commit".
```

So basically what I meant to say that it could be something else in your expression (like the hyphen in mine) that is interfering with the matching of the dot and ampersand.

Answer (score 2):

Working example script:

```
#!/bin/bash
regex='"name":"([a-zA-Z.@]+)"'
input='"name":"internal.action.retry.queue@temp"'

if [[ $input =~ $regex ]]
then
    echo "$input matches regex $regex"
    for (( i=0; i<${#BASH_REMATCH[@]}; i++))
    do
        echo -e "\tGroup[$i]: ${BASH_REMATCH[$i]}"
    done
else
    echo "$input does not match regex $regex"
fi
```

Comment: Hmm, this didn't work for me either. An examply string that the regex gets executed against is: http://pastebin.com/j3edCZtQ. It's the output to a curl

Comment: did you copy and paste my script into a file and run it? It works for me.

Answer (score 0):

Just add dot ('.') and at sign ('@'):

```
name\":\"(\.[a-zA-Z.@]+)\"
```

If you don't need mandatory dot at the beginnig of the URL, use this:

```
\"name\":\"([a-zA-Z.@]+)\"
```

Comment: Hmm this doesn't seem to match anymore: an example string is... "name":"internal.action.retry.queue@temp" I need to match internal.action.retry.queue@temp

Comment: @Nick Oh.  I thought that `\.` was there for reason.  Added variant without extra dot.